# Read two sheets and concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe with two sheets as below:

```
import pandas as pd

sheet_1 = pd.DataFrame({'KIFRS BS / IS': ['', 'CCY Type :', 'COA Code', '11000000000'], 
                   'Unnamed: 1': ['', 'EQU', 'COA English Name', 'ABC'],
                   'Unnamed: 2': ['', '', 'Base Currency Exchange Amt.', 1000],
                   'Unnamed: 3': ['26-11-2023', '', '', ''],
                   'Unnamed: 4': ['', 'Hanoi', '', '']})
sheet_2 = pd.DataFrame({'KIFRS BS / IS': ['', 'CCY Type :', 'COA Code', '11000000000'], 
                   'Unnamed: 1': ['', 'EQU', 'COA English Name', 'ABC'],
                   'Unnamed: 2': ['', '', 'Base Currency Exchange Amt.', 1200],
                   'Unnamed: 3': ['26-11-2023', '', '', ''],
                   'Unnamed: 4': ['', 'Hochiminh', '', '']})
```

and data will look like below:

```
    KIFRS BS / IS   Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4
0                                           26-11-2023  
1   CCY Type :  EQU                                     Hanoi
2   COA Code    COA English Name    Base Currency Exchange Amt.     
3   11000000000 ABC                 1000
```

Below is my expected output:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'COA Code': ['11000000000', '11000000000'], 
                   'COA English Name': ['ABC', 'ABC'],
                   'Base Currency Exchange Amt.': [1000, 1200],
                   'Base Date': ['26-11-2023', '26-11-2023'],
                   'Branch': ['Hanoi', 'Hochiminh']})   

COA Code        COA English Name    Base Currency Exchange Amt. Base Date   Branch
0   11000000000 ABC                 1000                        26-11-2023  Hanoi
1   11000000000 ABC                 1200                        26-11-2023  Hochiminh
```

To make expected Output, I did something as below:

```
base_date_1 = sheet_1.iloc[0,3]
branch_1 = sheet_1.iloc[1,4]
sheet_1.columns = sheet_1.iloc[2]
sheet_1 = sheet_1[3:]
sheet_1['Base Date'] = base_date_1
sheet_1['Branch'] = branch_1

base_date_2 = sheet_2.iloc[0,3]
branch_2 = sheet_2.iloc[1,4]
sheet_2.columns = sheet_2.iloc[2]
sheet_2 = sheet_2[3:]
sheet_2['Base Date'] = base_date_2
sheet_2['Branch'] = branch_2

output_2 = pd.concat([sheet_1, sheet_2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
output_2
```

It worked but in case there are more sheets then I need to define it manually. I tried with below code but it raised error that said `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iloc'`. What should I do to in this case. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

sheet_name = ['sheet_1', 'sheet_2']

for x in sheet_name:
    df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name = sheet_name)
    base_date_1 = df.iloc[0,3]
    branch_1 = df.iloc[1,4]
    df.columns = df.iloc[2]
    df = df[3:]
    df['Base Date'] = base_date_1
    df['Branch'] = branch_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parameter `sheet_name` use variable `x`, then create list of DataFrames by `append` and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
sheet_name = ['sheet_1', 'sheet_2']

out = []
for x in sheet_name:
    df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name = x)
    base_date_1 = df.iloc[0,3]
    branch_1 = df.iloc[1,4]
    df.columns = df.iloc[2]
    df = df[3:]
    df['Base Date'] = base_date_1
    df['Branch'] = branch_1
    out.append(df)

output = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
```

Or if specify multiple sheetnames get dictionary of `DataFrame`s, so for loop use `dict.items()`:

```
sheet_name = ['sheet_1', 'sheet_2']

dfs = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name = sheet_name)

out = []
for k, df in dfs.items():
    base_date_1 = df.iloc[0,3]
    branch_1 = df.iloc[1,4]
    df.columns = df.iloc[2]
    df = df[3:]
    df['Base Date'] = base_date_1
    df['Branch'] = branch_1
    out.append(df)

output = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
```